news application problem after building apk
I'm facing an issue with my Flutter news app. It works flawlessly in mobile emulators, but when I build and deploy the APK to a physical device, the app gets stuck on a loading screen. I haven't encountered any error messages or exceptions.
How can I troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

That could be due to network permission.
Do check your AndroidManifest.xml file if it contains <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> or not. Flutter by default does not require network permission in order to run on debug mode. But you must have provided the permission manually before build for production.
